# vb.net programatically add link button to datagrid -- click event not firing

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, onclick

I have a datagrid where I am programatically adding a linkbutton on ItemDataBound.

```
Protected Sub dgCounts_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles dgCounts.ItemDataBound

            For i As Integer = 1 To (e.Item.Cells.Count - 1)

                Dim lb As New LinkButton
                lb.CommandArgument = aryDealers(i)
                lb.Text = e.Item.Cells(i).Text
                lb.CausesValidation = False
                AddHandler lb.Click, AddressOf lb_Click

                If e.Item.Cells(i).Text.Trim.Length > 0 Then
                    e.Item.Cells(i).Controls.Add(lb)
                End If

            Next
End Sub

Protected Sub lb_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim lb As LinkButton = CType(sender, LinkButton)
        Dim s As String = lb.CommandArgument
End Sub
```

The linkbutton is adding to the grid cells correctly, but when you the click event is not firing.

Thoughts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not add controls dynamically in the DataGrid's [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemdatabound.aspx) Event (or GridView's [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx)-Event). `ItemDataBound` is only triggered when you databind the DataGrid to it's DataSource. If you've enabled `ViewState` and databind it only if `Not Page.IsPostback`, the control would not be recreated on postbacks. Therefore no events are triggered.

You should use [ItemCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemcreated.aspx) instead(RowCreated in GridView) to create controls dynamically, because `ItemCreated` is called on every postback.

Comment: I can't get the ItemCreated event to fire. I also don't know how I will have the access to the e.Item.Cells(i).Text to bind to the control in the ItemCreated event.

Comment: Simply add a `Handles dgCounts.ItemCreated` to your event handler. The rest is the same as in ItemDataBound. If you need to access values from the datasource to fill your dynamical controls, you need ItemCreated to create the control(s) and also ItemDataBound to fill them with values. You can access dynamical controls e.g. via `e.Item.FindControl("ControlID")` or via the control-collection(e.g. `e.Item.Cells(0).Text`).

Comment: Protected Sub dgCounts_ItemCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles dgCounts.ItemCreated won't hit the breakpoint.

Comment: i'm loading this from a dataset if that matters
        dgCounts.DataSource = BL.GetSeedCounts(region_id) 'returns dataset
        dgCounts.DataBind()

Comment: i have AutoGenerateColumns="true", does that matter?